# Raid Controller Issues on Dell XPS 8100 Tower

Tags: raid, dell-xps

I'm trying to upgrade a XPS 8100 i7 tower.

It has a IRST raid controller and Ive connected 2 x 4TB drives onto the board, but they are only showing at 1.6TB.

The new drives show up as 4TB on my Windows PC via a docking station.

As far as I am aware, the bios is up to date having ran the bios upgrade tool.

Any ideas much appreciated

John

[Raid Controller Config Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmE5j.jpg)

Comment: More than likely the old raid controller is having issues with the new advanced format drives.

Comment: Older controllers and older setups (including the classic BIOS firmware on most motherboards) only support up to 2TB drive size.  That is 2TiB (precisly). Add marketing terms and 2.7TiB drives are often sold as 3TB.  Now getting to the real comment: '4TB' *smells* like 3.6TiB with a 2TiB wraparound, yielding 1.6.

Comment: Wrap around as in, try counting with two cell.  01, 02, .. 98, 99, ...    '99'+'40' would be '139'. Only the first two figures fit so it would show '39'

Comment: @Moab  You were first to suggest that.  Care to write an answer?

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the old raid controller is having issues with the new advanced format drives you installed, or it is not capable of recognizing 4TB drives,